# Variables set in db_cursor1 cannot be used as where clause criteria in db_cursor2

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm not able to next cursors and and have the variables set from db_cursor1 used in the where clause of db_cursor2. By the time db_cursor2 declared it only works with the settings for @curLocation and @curTimeBandName at the time of declaration. I'm hoping "FETCH FIRST FROM db_cursor1 INTO @curLocation, @curTimeBandName" will set these variables to new values and I can do a new fetch on db_cursor2 with these new critera, but it doesn't work. I hate to move the declaration and deallocation for db_cursor2 inside the loop. It there a better way to next these cursors where the variables set in #1 can be used as criteria in #2.

```
DECLARE
    @Id INT,
    @prevId INT = 0,
    @prevEndDate DATETIME,
    @curStartDate DATETIME,
    @curEndDate DATETIME,
    @curLocation NVARCHAR(100) = 'PHX',
    @curTimeBandName NVARCHAR(50) = 'Long3'

SELECT @PrevEndDate = ISNULL(@startDate,'1900/01/01');

DECLARE db_cursor1 CURSOR 
SCROLL
FOR
SELECT DISTINCT [Location], TimeBandName
FROM #Temp  
ORDER BY Location, TimeBandName;

--  SELECT @curLocation = 'PHX', @curTimeBandName = 'Long3';
DECLARE db_cursor2 CURSOR 
SCROLL
FOR
SELECT Id, StartDate, EndDate
FROM #Temp
WHERE [Location] = @curLocation
    AND TimeBandName = @curTimeBandName
ORDER BY Location, TimeBandName,  StartDate;

OPEN db_cursor1

OPEN db_cursor2

FETCH FIRST FROM db_cursor1 INTO @curLocation, @curTimeBandName
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor2 INTO @Id, @curStartDate, @curEndDate

    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN
        IF (@prevEndDate + 1 < @curStartDate)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE t
                SET t.BlackoutStartDate = @PrevEndDate + 1,
                    t.BlackoutEndDate = @CurStartDate -1
            FROM #Temp t
            WHERE t.Id = @Id 
        END

        SELECT @prevId = @id, @prevEndDate = @curEndDate

        FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor2 INTO @Id, @curStartDate, @curEndDate
    END
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor1 INTO @curLocation, @curTimeBandName
END

CLOSE db_cursor2;
DEALLOCATE db_cursor2;

CLOSE db_cursor1;
DEALLOCATE db_cursor1;
```

Comment: "I hate to move ..." but you must. Is there a better way? Usually - find a set-based solution. You are updating a temp table which is not declared and probably doesn't have any constraints so no one but you knows what it represents and the intent of your design. If you post a script with DDL and sample data along with a description of what you are trying to achieve, someone might offer suggestion.

Comment: This looks like it was written before SQL Server supported windowing functions (or at least before the developer who wrote it was comfortable using them). To echo SMor, if you explain the logic and provide sample data, it's likely someone can help steer you to a set-based re-write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better way. I dumped the second cursor all together. Instead I added a ProcessStatus field to the temp table to track the next unfinished record and added the below code to track witch of the next records to work on.

```
WHILE ...
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1
            @Id = Id,
            @curStartDate = StartDate,
            @curEndDate = @EndDate
    FROM #Temp
    WHERE [Location] = @curLocation
        AND TimeBandName = @curTimeBandName
        AND ProcessStatus = 0
    ORDER BY Location, TimeBandName,  StartDate;

.... do work ...

    UPDATE  t
        SET ProcessStatus = 1
    FROM #Temp t
    WHERE Id = @Id;
END
```